# combine emoji with text in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, emoji

I am creating a calendar plot using ggcal with four labels for dates.

```
library(ggcal)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library('emo')

df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-02-18"), by="1 day"),
                 result = c(rep(c('Great', 'Good', 'Okay', 'Bad'), 4), 'DK', 'DK'))


ggcal(df$date, df$result) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('Great' = "forestgreen", 
                               'Good' = "palegreen3",
                               'Okay' = 'red3',
                               'Bad' = 'indianred3',
                               'DK' = 'grey77'))
}

> print(paste0(11, emo::ji('happy')))
[1] "11\U0001f64b"
```

Now, I want to combine emojis with the text for example happy emoji for great days, but if I use paste0, it prints the emoji code. 
Wanted to know if there was another way to combine emoji and text so that the actual emoji will be printed.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `cat()` rather than `print()`.

Comment: But how can I assign as variable name using cat in the df datarame

Comment: Well it’s not clear to me how you want to use these pasted values in the plot. What did you try and what didn’t work. I think the paste should be fine. It’s just when you print to console you need to use cat.

Comment: I want to change the values of the variable to be word + emoji in the df dataframe so I can use those in the legend passed to ggcal. Thanks